# Can not set my destination to Raneilles

Tags: eve-online

I can not set my destination to Raneilles. 
The 10th noob quest for military needed me to go there, I spent 1 hour trying to go, after failing I decided to drop the quest. (Is there a way to get it back?)

Now I am doing the 2nd quest for business, it wants me to go the same place.

There is no warp to location option
When I say set destination it says: “Can’t set waypoint to same location twice”
When I activate autopilot it says: “Autopilot engaged” 2 secs later: “Autopilot disabled - No waypoints set”

The route tab is empty i.e. “No Destination”

How am I going to go there?

(This only happens for Raneilles)

Edit:
As seen in this picture only the Raneilles is white while the others are yellow/green.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your not actually in Raneilles already?

Comment: I am at Clellinon Center for advanced studies school

Comment: That's really odd. When you're in space, does any stargate in your current system appear in yellow (that means it's part of your current route)?

Comment: they did in previous quests but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell you why your autopilot doesn't work, setting destination should work fine unless you accidentaly put Raneilles on to your "avoid system" autopilot blacklist.

But you can of course always fly manually if the autopilot fails you (happens more often than you might think) and plan your route with out of game resources like dotlan.

I prepared a navigation link on dotlan for you here:

http://evemaps.dotlan.net/route/Clellinon:Raneilles

Comment: I think it was in the "avoid system" part. I unchecked avoid systems and it worked. Where do I find that list and how do I get raneilles out again? and can I take the military quest I abandoned back somehow?

Comment: Hmm, you can access your avoidance list somewhere in the Map settings I think (accessable by pressing F10), but can't remember where exactly.

Abandoned missions are usually lost permanently, but with tutorial missions there might be an option to reset them somewhere. I never actually did those, so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: how did you learn the game without tutorial missions? it seems pretty complicated

Comment: I started the game 2009. There were some kind of tutorial missions then, but they were changed a lot. I think the missions as they are today did not exist in that form and extent as of 1 or 2 years ago.

Comment: Systems can be put on an avoid list automatically. It's been a while since I've played, but I believe the default autopilot settings avoids any systems deemed dangerous. This could include systems that are 0.4 security or lower, or a system where pilots have been podded. There might be other conditions. Also keep in mind that if all available routes to a destination includes a system on the avoidance list, you won't be able to navigate to it unless you adjust your autopilot settings.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to open people and places (alt e), search Raneilles, and set destination to one the stations. Once you're in the system you should be able to use the missions sidebar to warp directly to where you need to.

Comment: thats a good suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work